# How to handle an arbitrary number of intervals in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ansi-sql

I have two tables in a SQL database.  The first, `path`, holds points on a path (or trajectory).  Each point gets a row.

The second table, 'intervals' lists intervals over the path represented on the first table.  These have been identified as special in some way, for example a portion of the path where the object isn't moving much.

We expect multiple intervals to be identified on the path.

I would like to add a new column to the `path` table whose value represents whether that portion of the path is inside of one of these intervals.  I give an example of this additional column in the sample below.

If there were only a single interval I would use

```
CASE WHEN p.time BETWEEN i.Start_Time AND i.End_Time THEN True ELSE False END
```

What can I do instead to handle any number of intervals?

intervals:

```
| Interval ID | Start_Time | End_Time |
|-------------|------------|----------|
| 1           | 5          | 36       |
| 2           | 71         | 78       |
| 3           | 206        | 308      |
| ...         |            |          |
```

Here is an example of the `path` table with the desired 'at_rest' column successfully added.

```
| time | x | y  | at_rest |
|------|---|----|---------|
| 0    | 5 | 9  | 0       |
| 1    | 6 | 10 | 0       |
| 2    | 7 | 31 | 1       |
| 3    | 9 | 49 | 1       |
| ...  |   |    |         |
```

Comment: is path.at_rest an old existing column?  Or is it the name of your new column?  Or what would you like to name the new column?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also show the result that you want.

Comment: @donPablo I added some clarification to my text.  The meant for the 'at_rest' column is be the new column we are adding.  Sorry that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be different in different DBMSs.
I think this logic works, but the implementation depends on your environment.
I am assuming the intervals are not overlapping.

You can use a combination of `WHEN EXISTS` and `SELECT` statement inside a `CASE`:

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT Interval_ID
        FROM intervals
        WHERE p.time BETWEEN Start_Time AND End_Time
    ) THEN (
            SELECT Interval_ID
            FROM intervals
            WHERE p.time BETWEEN Start_Time AND End_Time
    )
     ELSE 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that having the Interval_ID is more meaningful than just a Yes/No indicator.  The column atRest preserves your initial concept of Yes/No.  Also, I added more data to the path table to get my results--

```
SELECT 
       [Path_time]
      ,[x]
      ,[y]
      ,[at_rest]
      ,ki.[Interval ID]
      ,Case When ki.[Interval ID] IS NULL  Then 0 Else 1 End as atRest
  FROM [StackOver].[dbo].[Keith_path]  as kp
  Left Join [StackOver].[dbo].[Keith_interval] as ki
  On kp.Path_time BETWEEN ki.Start_Time AND ki.End_Time
  Order By kp.Path_time
```

This would need to be turned into an Update sql to replace existing values.  Results are--

```
Path_time   x   y   at_rest IntervalID  atRest
0           5   9   0       NULL        0
1           6   10  0       NULL        0
2           7   31  1       NULL        0
3           7   33  0       NULL        0
4           7   32  0       NULL        0
5           8   31  0       1           1
6           9   30  0       1           1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one row with `true`/`false`, then use `exists`.  Many databases support boolean types directly, so you can just use:

```
select . . .,
       (exists (select 1
                from intervals i
                where p.time bertween i.start_time and i.end_time
               )
       ) as flag
```

In other databases, you need a `case` expression:

```
select . . .,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from intervals i
                          where p.time bertween i.start_time and i.end_time
                         )
             then 1 else 0
       ) as flag
```

Comment: Unfortunately there can be large numbers of rows that lie in a single interval.

Comment: @keith . . . So what?  This provides a flag that says if a given row is in *any* interval.

Answer (score 0):

The solution my coworker and I came up with uses the dreaded `CROSS JOIN` but we can filter our tables down to only a few thousand rows beforehand so that won't be such a problem.

```
WITH interval_path AS (SELECT path.*, intervals.*
FROM path
CROSS JOIN intervals
WHERE path.time BETWEEN intervals.Start_Time AND intervals.End_Time)

SELECT path.time, path.x, path.y, 
COALESCE(interval_path.in_cluster, 0) AS in_cluster
FROM path
LEFT JOIN interval_path ON interval_path.time = path.time
ORDER BY path.time
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by donPablo this can be solved (as you describe it) with a join:

```
WITH intervals AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM VALUES 
    (1,1,5,36)
    ,(1,2,71,78)
    ,(1,3,206,308) 
  v(unit_id, interval_id, start_time, end_time)
), paths AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM VALUES
    (1,0,5,9 )
    ,(1,1,6,10)
    ,(1,2,7,31)
    ,(1,3,9,49) 
    ,(1,4,9,48) 
    ,(1,5,9,47) 
    ,(1,6,9,46) 
    p(unit_id, time, x, y) 
)
SELECT p.unit_id
    ,p.time
    ,p.x
    ,p.y
    ,i.unit_id is not null as atRest
FROM paths p 
LEFT JOIN intervals i 
    ON p.unit_id = i.unit_id and p.time between i.start_time and i.end_time
order by 1,2;
```

giving:

```
UNIT_ID TIME    X   Y   ATREST
1   0   5   9   FALSE
1   1   6   10  FALSE
1   2   7   31  FALSE
1   3   9   49  FALSE
1   4   9   48  FALSE
1   5   9   47  TRUE
1   6   9   46  TRUE
```

Of note the example intervals you give do not imply "at rest" on first points you give, because those are not in an interval.

I also include a "unit_id" because have massive amount of data for only one entity is very unlikely.

Now, if your interval data was overlapping then you need to change a count:

```
WITH intervals AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM VALUES 
    (1,1,2,4)
    ,(1,2,4,6)
    ,(1,3,206,308) 
  v(unit_id, interval_id, start_time, end_time)
), paths AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM VALUES
    (1,0,5,9 )
    ,(1,1,6,10)
    ,(1,2,7,31)
    ,(1,3,9,49) 
    ,(1,4,9,48) 
    ,(1,5,9,47) 
    ,(1,6,9,46) 
    p(unit_id, time, x, y) 
)
SELECT p.unit_id
    ,p.time
    ,p.x
    ,p.y
    ,count(i.unit_id) > 0 as atRest
FROM paths p 
LEFT JOIN intervals i 
    ON p.unit_id = i.unit_id and p.time between i.start_time and i.end_time
group by 1,2,3,4
order by 1,2;
```

giving:

```
UNIT_ID TIME    X   Y   ATREST
1   0   5   9   FALSE
1   1   6   10  FALSE
1   2   7   31  TRUE
1   3   9   49  TRUE
1   4   9   48  TRUE
1   5   9   47  TRUE
1   6   9   46  TRUE
```

if you are wanting `0` or `1` as your at_rest values in snowflake swapping to the inline IFF is the most compact.

```
    ,iff(count(i.unit_id) > 0,1,0) as atRest
```